# Retrieving document types in xslt file in umbraco

Tags: .net, xslt, umbraco

Very new to Umbraco and .net, have been getting on fairly well putting my first site together. However, I've hit a bit of a stumbling block where I have set up a document type called Testimonial Article, which I want to retrieve and loop through in the XSLT file. I have set up a Macro which is linked to this XSLT file, and I've created and published a Testimonial Article - but there is no results seemingly.

I am assuming I am trying to access the document type incorrectly in the XSLT file?

In Testimonials.xslt, very basic:

```
<xsl:param name="currentPage"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="umbraco.library:GetXmlAll()//node[@nodeTypeAlias = 'TestimonialArticle']" >
    <p>Result</p>
</xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
```

I have created a Testimonial with document type Testimonial Article:

[image]

And this is my doc type:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe doing `//node` is the old way of doing it.  I've replaced it with an `//*`

Doing `//TestimonialArticle` should also work as well instead of `umbraco.library:GetXmlAll()//*[@nodeTypeAlias = 'TestimonialArticle']`

You may find this package helpful when creating your xpath: http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/umbraco-xpath-evaluator

```
<xsl:param name="currentPage"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="umbraco.library:GetXmlAll()//*[@nodeTypeAlias = 'TestimonialArticle']" >
    <p>Result</p>
</xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

with XSLT you'd normally start from some "referencePoint" - in Umbraco that is normally the currentPage variable, and then you go from there - (pseudo code): "currentpage - children - where documentType is .." etc

Have a look here: http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/xslt/the-basics